# ColdFusion ORM trying to insert into identity column

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a strange issue with ColdFusion ORM, it's trying to insert a value into my identity column after creating `EntityNew()` and then `EntitySave()`. Here is the particular property definition:

```
property name='StaffAdminID'
    fieldType='id'
    type='numeric'
    ormType='integer'
    generator='identity'
    setter=false
    insert=false
    update=false;
```

And here is the code creating a new record:

```
transaction {
    LOCAL.staffAdmin = EntityNew('StaffAdmins');
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setYear( REQUEST.user.getYear() );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setStaff( LOCAL.staff );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAdmin( LOCAL.admin );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAddedOn( Now() );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAddedBy( SESSION.username );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAddedID( REQUEST.user.getStaffID() );
    EntitySave( LOCAL.staffAdmin );
}
```

And here is the Hibernate log:

```
2015-07-24 21:49:20,108 [ajp-bio-8014-exec-6] Hibernate DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        StaffAdmins
        (AddedOn, AddedBy, AddedID, YearID, StaffEnrollmentID, AdminEnrollmentID, StaffAdminID, StaffID, AdminID) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateSessionException:
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
table 'StaffAdmins' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

As you can see, it's trying to insert into the `StaffAdminID` column with what I assume is `null`. I'm not sure what's going on, I even tried setting `dynamicInsert=true` on the Component. Any ideas would be great! Thanks

Comment: At this point, I'm using `QueryExecute()` to at least get a record into the database, and then retrieve the inserted record from the `result.generatedKey`. (sigh) It's hackish but works...

Answer (score 0):

You should actually get the mssql table with the primary key as IDENTITY(1,1)
 so it increments itself and then you dont need to give one staffadminid

Comment: It is, *Hibernate* wants me to change it to IDENTITY_INSERT = 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
property name="StaffAdminID" fieldtype="id" column="StaffAdminID" generator="identity" setter="false";
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes down to if the values in your `StaffAdminID` field need to be auto-generated. Since you're inserting the ID from the request scope, I would assume that you don't generate new `StaffAdmin` entries, so you could drop the `IDENTITY` on the field completely and not have a problem (if there is another table somewhere which does generate the IDs automatically, this doesn't mean the `StaffAdmin` table needs `IDENTITY` too).

If, however, you do need them auto-generated then I would turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` on somewhere before the `EntitySave` in your transaction like so:

```
transaction{
    LOCAL.staffAdmin = EntityNew('StaffAdmins');
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setYear( REQUEST.user.getYear() );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setStaff( LOCAL.staff );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAdmin( LOCAL.admin );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAddedOn( Now() );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAddedBy( SESSION.username );
    LOCAL.staffAdmin.setAddedID( REQUEST.user.getStaffID() ); 

    // This statement should turn IDENTITY_INSERT on for the rest of the transaction
    identityOn = queryExecute( 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT StaffAdmin ON' );

    // Save the entity (while IDENTITY_INSERT is on)
    EntitySave( LOCAL.staffAdmin );

    // Turn IDENTITY_INSERT off again for two reasons:
    // 1. Prevents accidental ID inserts by others
    // 2. Prevents an error being thrown when trying to set IDENTITY_INSERT on for another table
    identityOff = queryExecute( 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT StaffAdmin OFF' );
}
```

The above assumes your `application.datasource` is set - if not obviously add the options struct to [queryExecute](https://cfdocs.org/queryexecute) and specify the `datasource` property

For clarification on the 2nd reason (above) to turn the ID insert off again see the [remarks from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)